# Firebase authentication cause freeze in the screen I don't know why

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose

This is my MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private lateinit var navHostController: NavHostController

    private val deepLinkViewModel: DeepLinkViewModel by viewModel()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            KoinContext {
                CountryAppTheme {
                    Surface(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                    ) {
                        navHostController = rememberNavController()
                        deepLinkViewModel.handleDeepLink(intent, navHostController)
                        NavGraph(
                            navHostController = navHostController,
                        )
                        AuthState(navHostController = navHostController)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my AuthState composable

```
@Composable
fun AuthState(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    viewModel: AuthViewModel = koinViewModel(),
) {
    val isUserSignedOut = viewModel.getAuthState().collectAsState().value
    if (isUserSignedOut) {
        Log.i(TAG, "viewModel.isUserSignedOut: $isUserSignedOut ")
        NavigateToSignInScreen(navController = navHostController)
    } else {
        if (viewModel.isEmailVerified) {
            Log.i(TAG, "viewModel.isEmailVerified: ${viewModel.isEmailVerified}")
            NavigateToMapsScreen(navController = navHostController)
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "viewModel.isEmailNotVerified: ${viewModel.isEmailVerified}")
            NavigateToVerifyEmailScreen(navController = navHostController)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun NavigateToSignInScreen(navController: NavController) =
    navController.navigate(Screen.SignInScreen.route) {
        popUpTo(navController.graph.id) {
            inclusive = true
        }
    }

@Composable
private fun NavigateToMapsScreen(navController: NavController) =
    navController.navigate(Screen.TabLayoutScreen(args = "/${Locale.getDefault().displayCountry}").route) {
        popUpTo(navController.graph.id) {
            inclusive = true
        }
    }

@Composable
private fun NavigateToVerifyEmailScreen(navController: NavController) = navController.navigate(
    Screen.VerifyEmailScreen.route
) {
    popUpTo(navController.graph.id) {
        inclusive = true
    }
}
```

This is my Viewmodel

```
class AuthViewModel(
    private val repo: EmailAuthRepository
): ViewModel() {


    init {
        getAuthState()
    }

    fun getAuthState() = repo.getAuthState(viewModelScope = viewModelScope)

    val isEmailVerified get() = repo.currentUser?.isEmailVerified ?: false
}
```

This is my Repo

```
class EmailAuthRepositoryImpl(
    private val auth: FirebaseAuth,
    private val db: FirebaseFirestore,

    ) : EmailAuthRepository {

    override val currentUser: FirebaseUser?
        get() = auth.currentUser

    override fun getAuthState(viewModelScope: CoroutineScope) = callbackFlow {
        val authStateListener = AuthStateListener { auth ->
            trySend(auth.currentUser == null)
        }
        auth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
        awaitClose {
            auth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
        }
    }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), auth.currentUser == null)
}
```

I want to didn't freeze and wait in the sign in screen. It should be more smooth. I'am also open to find any other improvements and problems you see. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "the app is freeze for a while"? Did you run the code on an emulator or a real device? Do you get the same behavior on both devices?

Comment: It get stuck for while for both emulator and real device can you check the video I uploaded.
https://jmp.sh/s/t80A64F4ZDx7ntERK9B5

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot see at first glance what causes that delay.

Comment: did you recommend any code recommend? I thought of adding a loading state to the UI.

Comment: Adding a loading state sounds good.